# IllegalStateException In Android?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

- I have spinner and listview in my Activity.
- I'm retrieving all of the columns with average from my SQLite database table in
  my listview.
- I'm using the average function in the raw query with a group by clause.

When I run the app my application crashes.

I'm getting null pointer exception:

```
Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 6 and java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed.
```

Can someone help me someone please. Thanks in advance.

Here is my Activity code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.performance_details);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        databaseHelper.onOpen(db);

        spinneEmployeeName = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerPerformance_EmployeeName);
        loadSerachEmpName();
        spinneEmployeeName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                selectedEmployeeName = spinneEmployeeName.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                System.out.println("selectedEmployeeName " + selectedEmployeeName);

                String[] separated = selectedEmployeeName.split(" ");
                strSeparated_Id = separated[0].trim();
                Log.e("strSeparated_Id  = ",""+strSeparated_Id);
                System.out.println("strSeparated_Id  = " +strSeparated_Id);

                strSeparated_EmpName = separated[1].trim();
                Log.e("strSeparated_EmpName  = ",""+strSeparated_EmpName);
                System.out.println("strSeparated_EmpName = " +strSeparated_EmpName);


                 showPerformanceDetails();


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

}

    private void showPerformanceDetails()
    {
         list_PerformanceDetails = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_PerformanceDetails);

        ArrayList<Performance_Pojo> Performance_PojoList = new ArrayList<Performance_Pojo>();  
        Performance_PojoList.clear();   

        SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.e("strSeparated_Id  = ",""+strSeparated_Id);
        Log.d("Tag", strSeparated_Id);
        Cursor cursor = sqlDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT performance_month, AVG(performance_rate_one),  AVG(performance_rate_two),  AVG(performance_rate_three),  AVG(performance_rate_four),  AVG(performance_rate_five)  FROM performance where "+ "Emp_id" + " = ? " 
                +" GROUP BY performance_month",new String[]{String.valueOf(strSeparated_Id)});

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0) 
        { 
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    Performance_Pojo Performance_PojoListItems = new Performance_Pojo();  

                    Performance_PojoListItems.set_strPerformanceMonth(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_month")));
                    Performance_PojoListItems.set_strPerformance_rate_one(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_one")));
                    Performance_PojoListItems.set_strPerformance_rate_two(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_two")));
                    Performance_PojoListItems.set_strPerformance_rate_three(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_three")));
                    Performance_PojoListItems.set_strPerformance_rate_four(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_four")));
                    Performance_PojoListItems.set_strPerformance_rate_five(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_five")));

                    Performance_PojoList.add(Performance_PojoListItems);     

                }while (cursor.moveToNext());   
            }
            sqlDatabase.close();
            cursor.close();
        }



        PerformanceList_Adapter performanceList_Adapter = new PerformanceList_Adapter(Performance_Details.this, Performance_PojoList); 
        list_PerformanceDetails.setAdapter(performanceList_Adapter);


    }
```

Here is my Adapter  Class

```
public class PerformanceList_Adapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Performance_Pojo> Performance_List;

    public PerformanceList_Adapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<Performance_Pojo> performance_List) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        Performance_List = performance_List;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Performance_List.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Performance_List.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Performance_Pojo PerformanceListItems =Performance_List.get(position);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.performance_list_items, null);
        }


        TextView textView_Month = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_PerformanceMonth);
        textView_Month.setText(PerformanceListItems.get_strPerformanceMonth());

        TextView textView_RateOne = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_performance_rate_one);
        textView_RateOne.setText(PerformanceListItems.get_strPerformance_rate_one());

        TextView textView_RateTwo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_performance_rate_two);
        textView_RateTwo.setText(PerformanceListItems.get_strPerformance_rate_two());

        TextView textView_RateThree = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_performance_rate_three);
        textView_RateThree.setText(PerformanceListItems.get_strPerformance_rate_three());

        TextView textView_RateFour = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_performance_rate_four);
        textView_RateFour.setText(PerformanceListItems.get_strPerformance_rate_four());

        TextView textView_RateFive = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_performance_rate_five);
        textView_RateFive.setText(PerformanceListItems.get_strPerformance_rate_five());


        return convertView;


    }


}
```

Error and Exception AT the line

```
  Performance_PojoListItems.set_strPerformance_rate_one(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_one")));
```

Here is my Log Cat Error Info

```
07-01 16:43:31.746: E/CursorWindow(15747): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 6
07-01 16:43:31.746: D/AndroidRuntime(15747): Shutting down VM
07-01 16:43:31.746: W/dalvikvm(15747): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at com.sqlitedemo.Performance_Details.showPerformanceDetails(Performance_Details.java:92)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at com.sqlitedemo.Performance_Details.access$0(Performance_Details.java:70)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at com.sqlitedemo.Performance_Details$1.onItemSelected(Performance_Details.java:56)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:42)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:837)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-01 16:43:31.766: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is there any record which matches you sqlite query condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happeninig because you are fetching the value `AVG(performance_rate_one)` and while searching for the column with the name `performance_rate_one`. So getColumnIndex will return -1 and hence the error you are getting.

Either use `alias` in your query or use the column name as `AVG(performance_rate_one)` while fetching.

**EDIT**

For example: if in Query you select field as `AVG(performance_rate_one) as col1`

Then while fetching you should write `cursor.g‌​etColumnIndex("col1")`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used alias to column still getting same error of java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed

Comment: What alias did you use ?

Comment: like this =  Cursor cursor = sqlDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT performance_month, AVG(performance_rate_one) as col1,  AVG(performance_rate_two) as col2,  AVG(performance_rate_three) as col3,  AVG(performance_rate_four) as col4,  AVG(performance_rate_five) as col5 FROM performance where "+ "Emp_id" + " = ? " 
    +" GROUP BY performance_month",new String[]{String.valueOf(strSeparated_Id)});

Comment: And fetching part as well please

Comment: still getting same error and exception at code line  =      Performance_PojoListItems.set_strPerformanceMonth(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_month")));

Comment: Thanks of millions . Thank you so much my code is working .Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad that it helped you. Have fun coding :)